# Weird code example from "Realm of Racket"

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I am currently reading the book "Realm Of Racket", which I really like so far. However, in chapter 4 1/2, on page 74, there is one code example that I just don't get. Maybe my mind refuses to figure it out because I am on vacation, however, I simply don't get what it does.

```
(define (winners lst pred)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) (list pred)]
    [else
      (define fst (first lst))
      (if (score> (record-score pred) (record-score fst))
        (list pred)
        (cons pred (winners (rest lst) fst)))]))
```

They don't really explain it in the book. They give some hints, though:

- "The purpose of the function is to pick the first-place finishers from a list of game records."
- "We have a struct definition of the following shape: *(struct record (name score))*"
- "*lst* is a list of such records, and *pred* is one such record. Indeed, the
  original list is *(cons pred lst)*, and it is sorted according to score."
- "You understand that winners is a list-eating function and goes through one record at a time. When there is at least one other record, it picks the first one, names it *fst*, and compares the scores of *fst* and its predecessors. Depending on the outcome, all winning records have been picked off or winners has to continue the search for equal-scoring players."

I suppose that *`score>`* is a typo. Besides that I fully understand the code - in terms of syntax and semantics. I just don't get the practical use of that. What is this and why would somebody want that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the code you are displaying is just to show you how local definitions work. In the same example you also see `(define sorted-lst (sort lst ...))` which won't work at all.

Here is the whole example code from page 75, which has all the parts of page 74 in it:

```
(define (winning-players lst)
  (define sorted-lst (sort lst ...)) ;; local variable 
  (define (winners lst pred)         ;; locally defined procedure
    (cond
      [(empty? lst) (list pred)]
      [else
       (define fst (first lst))
       (if (score> (record-score pred) (record-score fst))           
           (list pred)           
           (cons pred (winners (rest lst) fst)))]))
  ;; START HERE:
  ;; uses both local variable and the locally defined procedure
  (winners (rest sorted-lst) (first sorted-lst)))
```

What they tried to show in the following code is that **outside `winning-players` you cannot access `sorted-list` nor  use the procedure `winners` since it's hidden in `winning-players`' scope.**

Eg. if you try to use `(winners ...)` in racket interactions windows you get:

> winners: undefined;  cannot reference undefined identifier

If you understood that you can continue to the fun in chapter 5 :)

Bundled with racket you have all the code from the code from the book under `racket/collects/realm`. There are 2 defintions of procedures called `winners`. The first in `chapter 10` and the second in `chapter 12`.

As for the answer to what the code does. There is errors in the code so we need to fix that. My guess is that score> compares the scores of two records. I'm guessing it's supposed to be like this:

```
(struct record (name score) #:transparent)
(define (winning-players lst)
  (define (score> e1 e2)  ; defines a new local procedure
    (> (record-score e1)  ; that compares two records 
       (record-score e2)))

  ;; define sorted-list to be lst sorted by score in decreasing order
  (define sorted-lst (sort lst score>))  
  ;; procedure winners reduces the list to the elements 
  ;; that have same score as pred
  (define (winners lst pred)            
    (cond
      [(empty? lst) (list pred)]
      [else
       (define fst (first lst))
       (if (score> pred fst)           ;; changed to work with records
           (list pred)           
           (cons pred (winners (rest lst) fst)))]))
  ;; START HERE:
  ;; uses both local variable and the locally defined procedure
  (winners (rest sorted-lst) (first sorted-lst))) 

(define scores (list (record "John" 10) 
                     (record "Ben" 5) 
                     (record "Mary" 10) 
                     (record "Owen" 2)))  

(winning-players scores) 
; ==> (list (record "John" 10) (record "Mary" 10))
```

It returns a list of all the ones with the highest score.

Comment: I don't see what does it matter whether it's internal definition or not. The OP posted the code and asked what it does. As to why this code `(sort lst ...)` is written that way, maybe it's to cause a reader to *think*, in *which* order should the list be sorted.

Comment: @WillNess The code was broken. The purpose of that section of the book is to explain how define works within a procedure. Anyway, since you did point out I didn't actually answer I made an effort to try getting the code working and added that. It seems I agree with your conclusion :)

Comment: Why "broken"? `winners` is fully &correctly defined. The `sort`-calling form is missing just one ingredient, the comparison predicate. Also, it's obviously the intent of the author(s) that `score>` compares *scores of records*, not *records*, no need to change that. With the  definition `(struct record (name score))` most probably the accessor functions are automatically defined: `record-name` and `record-score`. But "scores" presumably don't *have* to be numeric or the authors just wanted to preserve the generality of the code. Plus they get to redefine it easily, e.g. `(define score> <)`. :)

Comment: @WillNess the struct supplies the accessors. The comparison predicate need to be something similar to what I added since you are comparing records. They couldn't use lambda since it's not due until chapter 7. If i had something that compared records already I would reused it. I'm just guessing of course since the example is incomplete and in the book *the chapter is about how you can define things locally and nothing else*.

Comment: clearly `score>` in `(score> (record-score pred) (record-score fst))` compares records' scores. If you mean they couldn't use `lambda` in `(sort lst ...)`, then OK, that's why they put `...` *there*. You could've added another internal definition in its stead, without re-writing `winners` at all, too. :) -- So you were talking about whole code as in the book; I was talking about the (partial) code that the OP showed. *That's* the misunderstanding.

Comment: @WillNess You are right. One could make another comparison function to use solely in sort, but none of us would have written winners without reusing it. I happen to have the book and I think it's an error not to have working code samples.

Answer (score 4):

```
(winners (cdr lst) (car lst))
```

produces the non-decreasing streak of records in `lst`. `pred` stands for "predecessor" (in the list). I assume `score>` is a procedure which compares scores of records (i.e. `record-score` seems to produce score of a record, and `score>` compares these scores).

IOW for a given list `lst` its prefix is produced such that the scores of record entries in it are in non-decreasing order.

The description states that the list is *sorted* before `winners` is applied. This only makes sense if it is sorted in *decreasing* order of record's score. Than that non-decreasing prefix of a decreasing list will actually contain records all with equal score - the maximal one. The "winners".

The precondition of the list being sorted in non-increasing order should have been stated *much more clearly and prominently* there.